# React Navigation - how to sync webview loaded pages with navigato

Tags: react-native, webview, expo

I am just learning react native (expo) with WebView. I am working on an app that needs to utilise our existing website pages(react, nextjs) as much as possible.

Main issue I can see is syncing webview loaded pages with the app e.g. if I click on the link within the webview to update go back button and header title.

Is the approach below valid and considered a good pratice or there is something I missed from documentation that is more recommended:

1. Inside of the website that is being loaded in webview when I click on the link, I would detect that this is webview loaded env and I would postMessage instead to the app with the url and all other data so that I can then redirect to a different screen in my app and load that url inside of the webview. This way I would have the native feel by and titles / go back buttons etc would be always updated on time.

If thats not recommended, and this would be not very performant how would you recommend to handle updating the react native app when you navigate within the webview.

Thanks

I have tried using build in webview methods to listen to changes e.g. of url and set e.g. header options from there. It seems to be working fine however this coule become complex fairly quickly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Its more an architectural question rather then code specific so I am not sure what code you need dear Bot.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to listen to postMessage events and handle callbacks accordingly. Listening to navigation changes on website can be delayed and will not be performant at times. There is nothing else that can be done on the webview side as per my knowledge.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).